# How to stop plots printing twice in jupyter when using subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, seaborn

I'm working with the titanic data and I'm trying to use a combination of pyplot and seaborn to produce some subplots. 
I've written the following code to create 6 subplots in a 3x2 grid;

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
plt.tight_layout()

_ = sns.catplot(x='Pclass', y='Age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[0, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='Embarked', y='Age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[0, 1])
_ = sns.catplot(x='Sex', y='Age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[1, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='Sex', y='Age', hue='Pclass', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[1, 1])
_ = sns.catplot(x='SibSp', y='Age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[2, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='Parch', y='Age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, palette=col_pal, ax=axes[2, 1])
plt.show()
```

When I run this in my notebook, it succesfully creates the desired plot, however, it also prints out 6 blank plots afterwards.
[image]

How can I suppress these empty plots from printing into my output?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other sns plots `catplot` generates a fig not an axes. That's why to fix such weird behavior you need to use `plt.close()` after each `catplot` execution:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 12))
fig.tight_layout()

sns.catplot(x='pclass', y='age', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[0, 0])
plt.close()
sns.catplot(x='embarked', y='age', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[0, 1])
plt.close()
sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[1, 0])
plt.close()
sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', hue='pclass', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[1, 1])
plt.close()
sns.catplot(x='sibsp', y='age', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[2, 0])
plt.close()
sns.catplot(x='parch', y='age', data=data, kind='box', ax=axes[2, 1]);
plt.close()

plt.show()
```

Out:

[image: catplots]

Answer (score 0):

Assign each of your plots to a variable like `g`, and use `plt.close(g.fig)` to remove your unwanted subplots. Or iterate over all `sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid` type variables and close them like so:

```
for p in plots_names:
    plt.close(vars()[p].fig)
```

The complete snippet below does just that. Note that I'm loading the titanic dataset using `train_df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")`. Here, all column names are lower case unlike in your example. I've also removed the `palette=col_pal` argument since `col_pal` is not defined in your snippet.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
plt.tight_layout()

train_df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(x='pclass', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[0, 0])
h = sns.catplot(x='embarked', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[0, 1])
i = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[1, 0])
j = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', hue='pclass', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[1, 1])
k = sns.catplot(x='sibsp', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[2, 0])
l = sns.catplot(x='parch', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[2, 1])

# iterate over plots and run
# plt.close() to prevent duplicate
# subplot setup
var_dict = vars().copy()
var_keys = var_dict.keys()
plots_names = [x for x in var_keys if isinstance(var_dict[x], sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid)]
for p in plots_names:
    plt.close(vars()[p].fig)
```

Please note that you ***will have to assign your plots to variable names*** for this to work. If you just add the snippet that closes the plots to the end of your original snippet, the duplicate subplot setup will remain untouched.

**Code 2:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
plt.tight_layout()

train_df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

_ = sns.catplot(x='pclass', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[0, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='embarked', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[0, 1])
_ = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[1, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='sex', y='age', hue='pclass', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[1, 1])
_ = sns.catplot(x='sibsp', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[2, 0])
_ = sns.catplot(x='parch', y='age', data=train_df, kind='box', height=8, ax=axes[2, 1])

# iterate over plots and run
# plt.close() to prevent duplicate
# subplot setup
var_dict = vars().copy()
var_keys = var_dict.keys()
plots_names = [x for x in var_keys if isinstance(var_dict[x], sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid)]
for p in plots_names:
    plt.close(vars()[p].fig)
```

**Plot 2:**

[image]