# How to iterate over all existing plots in a namespace?

Tags: python

I've created a bunch of plots and would like to subset a few of them by their characteristics. How can I loop through the namespace and make a list of some or all of them? And maybe even do operations on some of them using list comprehensions? I know this can be easily done with dataframes like in some of the answers to the question [Iterating over different data frames using an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536802/iterating-over-different-data-frames-using-an-iterator/48561001#48561001)

A practical example for plots could be to close some plots like in [How to stop plots printing twice in jupyter when using subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042218/how-to-stop-plots-printing-twice-in-jupyter-when-using-subplots/60044816#60044816) where you have to run `plt.close(g.fig)` where `g` is one of many plots in order to prevent a duplicate subplot setup.

**Setup:**

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]
df = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

g=sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=df, ax=axes[0, 0])
h=sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=df, ax=axes[0, 1])
i=sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=df, ax=axes[1, 0])
j=sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=df, ax=axes[1, 1])
```

In this example, how can I loop over i for `[g, h, i, j]` and run `plt.close(i.fig)` without explicitly naming each plot?

**What I've tried:**

Running `vars()` will return, among other things, `'g', 'h', 'i', j`. And running `vars()['g']`
 will give me `<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x1c1bc940>`. So i thought one option to would be to run 
`[elem for elem in vars() if elem in 'seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid']` to access each plot without using the specific names. But this will return `['g', 'i', 't', 's', 'ax']`, where `h` and `j` are missing although running `vars()['h']` will indeed return `<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x1bfa74a8>`.

And there does not seem to be any trace of `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid` in the output from `vars()['ax']` which is `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1c1bce10>`. And the output for `vars()['t']` and `vars()['t']` are long arrays of floats.

I guess I may be approaching this thing in a completely wrong way. Any other suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to be clear, I am not in any manner familiar with how `seaborn` works. What I was able to do with your setup code was the following -

```
var_dict = vars().copy()
var_keys = var_dict.keys()

plots_names = [x for x in var_keys if isinstance(var_dict[x], sns.axisgrid.FacetGrid)]
print(plots_names )
```

I had to make a copy of `vars()` since it changes as you iterate over it. Using the builtin function `isinstance()` I looked for all instances of `seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid` in the copy of `vars()` and returned all the keys that matched in a list. This is the output -

```
['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```